# Finding a general formula for the sequence {$0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15$}.

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm working on a mathematical model which requires me to generalize the elements of an infinite set. The element n is the nth finite sequence of the set.

For:

```
n = 1: {0}

n = 2: {0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15}

n = 3: {0, 1, 2, 5, 26, 29, 32, 81, 83, 87, 107, 112, 113, 116, 135, 140, 141, 142, 143, 161, 162, 194, 224, 351, 353, 356, 364, 365, 377, 647, 728, 1514, 1536, 1538, 1595, 1601, 1617, 1619, 1862, 2271, 2273, 2300, 2460, 2462, 2541, 2543, 2561, 3028, 3029, 3168, 3280, 3281, 3289, 3293, 3785, 3806, 3968, 4001, 4009, 4017, 4018, 4019, 4022, 4037, 4046, 4048, 4049, 4069, 4100, 4130, 4289, 4373, 5975, 6056, 6209, 6317, 6336, 6479, 6560, 6673, 6674, 7381, 8180, 9104, 9113, 9833, 9840, 9841, 9842, 9854, 10598, 10609, 10610, 11453, 12301, 13121, 13265, 13346, 14001, 14741, 15227, 15665, 16402, 17141, 17222, 17411, 18146, 18914, 19115, 19331, 19520, 19601, 19682}
```

OEIS doesn't have the sequence `n = 2` or `n = 3`, let alone a master sequence, so I'm kinda stuck. Does anyone know any math magic to help me generalize the set of sequences. I can provide sequences for n > 3 if necessary. I can also provide the algorithm (c-code) and/or system of equations I'm using to generate these finite sequences.

Weird, right? I have an indirect method for generating these sequences, but no direct function. If you don't have an answer, that's understandable, but any advice for a plan of attack would surely help.

Thanks for your time, assuming you take the time to read this.

---

**Update as requested:**

Origin of the family of sequences:

Generate an ordered, finite set $T_n:  T_n = \{A_1,...,A_\mu...,A_n\} $, and an operator $\circ: A_p \circ A_q ∈ T_n$.

For $A_\mu ∈ T_n,\ P(A_\mu)$ is the position of $A_\mu$ in set $T_n$.

Further, let:

$1. \ \ \ Q_k := (A_X \circ A_Y)_k$

$2.\ \ \ P(Q_k) = \left \lfloor{k\cdot n^{n*P(A_X)+P(A_Y)+1-{n^2}}} \right \rfloor\mod n:0\le k\lt n^{n^2}$

Then associativity of $\circ$ on the set $T_n$ requires that:

$ \bigl((A_X \circ A_Y)_k \circ A_Z\bigr)_k = \bigl(A_X \circ (A_Y \circ A_Z)_k\bigr)_k$.

Once you select a given $n$, we seek the instances $k$ for which the set $T_n$ is associative. There is typically more than one solution, $k$. The solutions of k for a given n generate the sequences written above.

Hence my dilemma:

I have an algorithm for generating the numbers, but can't see through the math in order to find a general function that generates all of the finite sequences, and I'm hoping for a fresh perspective, maybe a technique or something, to hopefully find said function.

Again, thanks for your input. I can do the work, but I'll appreciate a nudge in the right direction. :)

Comment: It seems that you *do* already have an algorithm to determine those sets!?

Comment: If you have setup some kind of recursion you should try a proof by induction

Comment: Please include how you are generating these sequences. You say that the sequence for $n=2$ is not in OEIS, but pasting it in (without the $0$) yields the initial segment of [A242883](http://oeis.org/A242883).

Comment: As mentioned by Benjamin, we have to know the meaning of the entries of the seuquences. Without this information, noone will be able to find a formula.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll add the algorithm I'm using to generate the sequences to the original post. Many thanks everyone

Comment: Why the group-theory tags?

Comment: Regarding your remark "Weird, right?", there's nothing particularly weird about defining things using recursion formulas, it's done *all* the time. There's even a terminology for this, [Definition by Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312664/what-is-formally-to-define-a-function-by-induction). And applying the principle of mathematical induction lets us work with objects defined by induction, without ever having an explicit formula for those objects.

Comment: +Gerry I started learning about groups a few days ago and noticed that the elements of associative groups were presented as sets of permutation operators of a set under a bijective operator. This view works and I've come across it a lot but it also seems 'limited'. If there is more than one solution for k for a particular n, then the set of permutations is not the only way to generate an associative group. All the same, it's possible that I misused the group-theory tags. I hope this response helps.

Comment: +Lee thanks for pointing me to that link, I didn't realize definitions by induction were a thing. Hehe I guess what's weird here is how little I understand. I'll read the link and hopefully that will get me somewhere. Kudos :)

Comment: I cannot make sense of your update.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Set T and $\circ$ make a group of ordered elements. P(X) tells us the location of X in T. x,y ∈ T, Q := x $\circ$ y, and Q ∈ T  so P(Q) is the location of Q in T. But what really is Q?

There are many possibilities for what Q is and we index them all with variable k.

The sequences are values of k such that the operators are associative and closed on the set T of n elements. I hope that explanation helps.

Comment: I suspect this could be phrased in terms of sets of the form $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ and permutations (and then $P$ is just the identity), but this is all too obscure right now.

Comment: Associativity of a set is not a thing. It is a binary operation on a set that may, or may not, be associative.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make any sense of this.  Can you explain how you get the list for $n = 2$?  Seems we should start with $T_2 = \{A_1, A_2\}$.  And then?

Comment: you write: "Generate an ordered, finite set $T_n:  T_n = \{A_1,...,A_\mu...,A_n\} .$" But isn't  $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ such a set? So can I use the set $T_n = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: @miracle173: I would think so.  This feels over-formalized; it (or *something*) is getting in the way of understanding the problem.

Comment: @BrianTung sorry for the late response. Yes, I can explain how we get the sequence for n=2.

T = {0,1}, a 2 element set. We seek all associative operators that can be defined for this set (respecting closure, nothing else is forced). So we generate a 2x2 table with 0,1 as vertical entries, and 0,1 as horizontal entries. There are four spaces where we can put the result of 0*0, 0*1, 1*0, 1*1. * is our operator, and whatever goes into the blanks defines the operator exhaustively. Associativity requires that if a,b,c are instances of elements of the set T_n, (a*b)*c=a*(b*c) (continuing soon...)

Comment: Since there are 4 blanks, and either 0 or 1 could go in them, there are 2^4 possible definitions for our operator *. This also corresponds to a binary table being filled from 0 to 15 (convince yourself of this). The k'th operator is thus defined as 0<=k<=n^(n^2), which is 0<=k<(16-1) in our case. Now all you have to do is check by computer which operators, k, produce tables that are associative. The k's that do are the set n=2 in the question. So of 16 possible operators, 8 are associative.

Comment: For example, k=7 means the table would be as follows.

7 base 10 = 0111 base 2. So:

Row 1: 0, 1
Row 2: 1, 1

This means we have an operator k_7 such that 0*0 = 0, 0*1 = 1, 1*0 = 1, 1*1 = 1. The other 7 values of the set for n=2 correspond to other viable associative operators. I haven't updated this thread but I found that whenever k corresponds to a prime number or 1, the difference between said primes is always a multiple of n. Also, every table has n! permutations, so some operators are isomorphic. Eg. there are only 5 "unique" associative operators for n=2. Still no pattern though.

Comment: So the way that I would put this (if I understand it correctly) is that for $n = 2$, you collect the encodings of associative binary operators.  You've listed $A \circ B = 0, A \wedge B, A, B, A \oplus B, A \vee B, A \odot B, 1$, which are encoded $0000, 0001, 0011, 0101, 0110, 0111, 1001, 1111$, respectively.  (I will assume you've collected these correctly; at first glance, they look right.)  Then for $n = 3$, you collect the encodings of associative operators on two ternary inputs, and for general $n$, you collect the encodings of associative operators on two $n$-ary inputs.  Is that right?

Comment: @BrianTung that's precisely right 

Comment: @McMath please repair your question. remove the wrong formalization and replace it by the explanation you give to BrianTung in the comments. You also should replace your title by a better one like 'finding all  semigroups of a given order' or 'finding all associative operation of a given number of elements' or something else.  A the moment there is no chance that somebody is interested in this topic will find your post. And if she finds it she cannot find out what you are doing she reads the post. only from the discussion with Brian this will become clear.

Comment: I can make the question clearer, that’s no problem, but my formalization isn’t wrong. It’s just how I process information. I apologize for not being formally educated beyond high school, I don’t know the standard way to say many things. I’m doing my best to get my thoughts across

Comment: @miracle173 I’ll edit the question properly soon, thank you for your advice