# How rigorous is it to construct a sequence by induction?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, recursion

For example, let's prove that if $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not bounded above, then there exists a subsequence $\{ a_{k_n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that diverges to $+\infty$.

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above. Set $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{k_0} > 0$. Among the terms $a_n$ for $n > k_0$, there must be some $a_q > 1$ for $q > k_0$ (else the sequence is bounded above by $\max \{1, \max \{a_n : n \leq k_0\}\}$). Set $k_1 = q > k_0$. Now assume for some $\beta \geq 1$ we have a subsequence $(a_{k_0}, a_{k_1}, \dots, a_{k_\beta})$ such that $a_{k_j} > j$ for each $j \in \{0, \dots, \beta\}$. Then there must be some $r > k_\beta$ such that $a_r > \beta + 1$, so setting $k_{\beta + 1} = r$ yields a subsequence $(a_{k_0}, a_{k_1}, \dots, a_{k_\beta}, a_{k_{\beta + 1}})$ such that $a_{k_j} > j$ for each $j \in \{0, \dots, \beta, \beta + 1\}$. Therefore, the proposition "we can construct a subsequence of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ terms such that *blah*" satisfies the inductive step and base, so by induction it is true for any **finite** $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Apparently, this implies we can construct an **infinitely** long subsequence $\{a_{k_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the property we want? How can we make this conclusion? Perhaps some connection to thinking of a real-valued sequence as a function $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ for $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

---

EDIT: based on the comments, induction is indeed not a valid technique for proving the existence of a sequence. The appropriate technique is recursion? How would one reformulate this proof (particularly the ending) to justify the existence of a subsequence $\{a_{k_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the property that $a_{k_j} > j$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Maybe it's just me (and the time of day), but your profusion of subscripted and multiply-subscripted symbols is more obscuring than clarifying. Keep in mind that for something like this (paragraph style in words), any proof you present is really a meta-logic argument that a formal proof exists. As for your question, I believe your use of induction shows that for any positive integer $n$ the process can be continued so as to produce a subsequence of length $n,$ and not the entire subsequence itself. That is, rather than *infinitely long subsequence*, you only get *arbitrarily long subsequence*.

Comment: What you want is the [definition by induction theorem](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~matti/definition-by-induction.pdf).

Comment: What you’re doing is properly called constructing a subsequence by **recursion**, not by induction; induction is properly a method of proof. And what you’ve done is a perfectly legitimate recursive construction. There is a theorem in set theory, the recursion theorem, that justifies such constructions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312664/what-is-formally-to-define-a-function-by-induction for a closely related statement.

Comment: The recursion theorem